# extracting pixel values above a value per polygon in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a shapefile containing 38 polygons i.e. 38 states of a country. This shapefile is overlaid on a raster. I need to extract/reclassify pixel above a certain value, specific to each polygon. 
For example, I need to extract the raster pixels> 120 for state/polygon 1, pixels> 189 for polygon 2 etc with the resulting raster being the extracted pixels with value 1 and everything else as NoData. Hence, it seems like I need to extract first and then reclassify.

I have the valuees, for extraction, saved as a data frame with a column containing names, matching the names of the states,which is stored as an attribute "Name" in the shapefile.

Any suggestion on how I could go about this?
Should I extract the raster for each state into 38 separate rasters, then do reclassify () and then mosaic to make one raster i.e. the country?

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible example. `?raster::rasterize` or `?raster::extract` may be a starting point for some example data.

Comment: From what I understand, it seems you could also achieve that in a more "data.frame-based" way. Then, `?sp::over` could also be a good starting point. With a reproducible example, you'd get a useful answer (e.g.: create a small raster, 3 polygons, and illustrate what you want - this is also a way to learn)...